# How to insert using greatest value of a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two types of inserts, one for new comments in a post and one is for response to another comment.

The response to comment is

```
INSERT INTO event_comments(e_id, thread_id, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes)
```

For a new comment how can I insert using the highest value of thread_id?

[image: l]

But for a new comment how can I use thread_id's value of 1 to insert?
I would be inserting the value 2 since the current highest thread_id value is 1

```
INSERT INTO event_comments(e_id, thread_id, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes)
VALUES(
   ..., 2, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...
)
```

Comment: You should have a separate `threads` table and take the `id` value from there as a foreign key in your `event_comments` table

Comment: what do you mean? so I just have a single threads table that have 1,2,3.. with no duplicates?

Comment: Yes a threads table with ID and all the info that defines a thread like a name.

Comment: can you explain a little on why I need to do that? that means when I insert a new comment into event_comments I need to insert a new one in threads_table. Whats wrong with using the INSERT INTO ... SELECT?

Comment: You should read up on databse normalization and database design. It it very odd having only an ID without a table for it. Smells like a design flaw. But that is way to much to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  For example, for doing an insert with `e_id = 1`, you may try:

```
INSERT INTO event_comments(e_id, thread_id, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes)
SELECT e_id, thread_id + 1, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes
FROM event_comments
WHERE e_id = 1;
```

Note the above insert is still a single statement, and so should be atomic.  That is, even if other threads are also reading and trying to do inserts, they should not interfere.

Comment: You can use the `max` function, if there are several threads

```INSERT INTO event_comments(e_id, thread_id, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes)
SELECT e_id, max(thread_id) + 1, .....
FROM event_comments
WHERE e_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest `threadID` using `ORDER BY` and limit result to 1.

```
INSERT INTO event_comments(e_id, thread_id, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes)
SELECT e_id, thread_id + 1, date_posted, is_root, created_by, body, num_likes
FROM event_comments
ORDER BY thread_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a nullable `thread_id` field that contains the id of the parent. A new thread is a comment with an empty `thread_id`. This also allows for nested threads. This also removes the need for an `is_root` field. I would also add a `page_id` with a foreign key to the pages table (or with the page url in it, if you do not have that table).